# How to change a circle into a square with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

After appending 25 circles to the page, I run the following function:

```
var transitionPage = function () {
  startThePage();
  var height = $(document).height() - 20
    , width = $(document).width()
    ;

  d3.selectAll("circle")
    .transition().duration(2500)
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("r", 15)
    .transition().duration(1000)
      .attr("cy", (height / 2))
    .each(function (d, i) {
      d3.select(this)
        .transition().duration(1000)
        .attr("cx", 30 + (i * width / 25));
    });
}
```

This works well and correctly lines them up horizontally along the middle of the page.

However, I couldn't figure out how to then transform each circle into a square or rectangle.

How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the svg recomendation there are no transformation possible for the circle shape to become a square. What you can try to do, and if you have control over this part, is to draw squares instead of circles and apply a border radius on it. Something like this:

```
d3.select("body").select("svg").append("rect")
    .attr("rx",100)
    .attr("ry",100)
    .attr("x",100)
    .attr("y",100)
    .attr("width",100)
    .attr("height",100)
    .attr("stroke","black")
    .attr("fill","white");
```

Then the transition from a circle to a square could be done as:

```
d3.select("rect")
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("rx",0)
    .attr("ry",0);
```

Comment: This was one of the first questions I asked after joining this site, when I was just starting to learn to program. I'd like to think I told myself to remember to come back and give this an up-vote after I hit 15 rep, but I guess I forgot. Your answer helped me make the home page for http://gablesmao.com (I'm surprised the site's still available). Anyway, after almost 2 years, here's your well-deserved +1.

Comment: Here's a demo:
http://bl.ocks.org/ericsoco/1470dd23c29b2095635b1e7e20b75f44