# D3 svg-path transition wiggles around (inclusive jsfiddle)

Tags: javascript, svg, path, d3.js, transition

I want to make a transition between a rect and a circle with d3.js.

my attempt is here: http://jsfiddle.net/8kxBW/1/

But for me that transition doesn't look smooth. 
Has anyone an idea how to improve the transition?

Is there a easy way to do that?

```
var circleDAttribute = "m4,15.75c0,-6.90608 5.59392,-12.5 12.5,-12.5c6.90608,0     12.5,5.59392 12.5,12.5c0,6.90608 -5.59392,12.5 -12.5,12.5c-6.90608,0 -12.5,-5.59392 -12.5,-12.5z";
var rectDAttribute = "m1.75,1.75l0,40l80.25,0l-0.25,-40l-80,0z";

d3.select("#pathTransition")
     .append("svg").append("g")
        .attr("transform","translate(60,60)")
     .append("path")
            .attr("d",rectDAttribute)
            .transition()
            .duration(3000)
            .attr("fill","blue")
            .transition()
            .duration(8000)
            .attr("d",circleDAttribute);
```

Comment: The [superformula explorer](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1021103) should help here.

Comment: Oh and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437408/how-do-i-change-a-circle-to-a-square-using-d3).

Comment: Thank you!! Superformula is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Great, I'll add that as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [superformula explorer](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1021103) allows you to transition between these shapes and many more.