# D3 how to change a circle to rectangle on a mouseover

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a project in D3 – and at the moment **I wanna change a circle into a rectangle when a user hover over a circle,** but I don't know how I have to start.

My starting point is the circle (->transition into rectangle).

```
svg.selectAll(".circle")
  .on('mouseover', function(d){
  d3.selectAll(".circle")
  .transition()
  .attr (...)
})
```

Is this the right approach? I know there is a similar question ([How to change a circle into a square with d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437408/how-to-change-a-circle-into-a-square-with-d3-js)) but I think this is not the right way for my purpose. But really – I'm not sure^^

Comment: I think it's the right direction -- Do you want the circle to change to a rectangle when the user hovers over the circle, or when the user hovers over something else like a button?  Right now you are doing the former since you have the mouseover listener bound to the circle.

Comment: Why do you think the approach in the other question is not right? It looks like it's exactly the same thing.

Comment: yes, you're right. sorry. when a user hover over a circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is to follow what the answer in the other question mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/a/17439344/21061 however there is another way of doing this.

The tricky part is, SVG can't animate an `svg:circle` to an `svg:square`. It can however animate any `svg:path` into any other `svg:path`, and you can leverage this to actually produce a nice transition between a circle and a square. I've simplified the example from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1020902 to demonstrate:

```js
(function(){function n(n,a,r){for(var e,s,o,m=-1,u=2*Math.PI/a,b=0,h=[];++m<a;)e=n.m*(m*u-Math.PI)/4,e=Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.cos(e)/n.a),n.n2)+Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.sin(e)/n.b),n.n3)),-1/n.n1),e>b&&(b=e),h.push(e);for(b=r*Math.SQRT1_2/b,m=-1;++m<a;)s=(e=h[m]*b)*Math.cos(m*u),o=e*Math.sin(m*u),h[m]=[Math.abs(s)<1e-6?0:s,Math.abs(o)<1e-6?0:o];return t(h)+"Z"}var a=d3.svg.symbol(),t=d3.svg.line();d3.superformula=function(){function t(a,t){var u,b=r[e.call(this,a,t)];for(u in m)b[u]=m[u].call(this,a,t);return n(b,o.call(this,a,t),Math.sqrt(s.call(this,a,t)))}var e=a.type(),s=a.size(),o=s,m={};return t.type=function(n){return arguments.length?(e=d3.functor(n),t):e},t.param=function(n,a){return arguments.length<2?m[n]:(m[n]=d3.functor(a),t)},t.size=function(n){return arguments.length?(s=d3.functor(n),t):s},t.segments=function(n){return arguments.length?(o=d3.functor(n),t):o},t};var r={asterisk:{m:12,n1:.3,n2:0,n3:10,a:1,b:1},bean:{m:2,n1:1,n2:4,n3:8,a:1,b:1},butterfly:{m:3,n1:1,n2:6,n3:2,a:.6,b:1},circle:{m:4,n1:2,n2:2,n3:2,a:1,b:1},clover:{m:6,n1:.3,n2:0,n3:10,a:1,b:1},cloverFour:{m:8,n1:10,n2:-1,n3:-8,a:1,b:1},cross:{m:8,n1:1.3,n2:.01,n3:8,a:1,b:1},diamond:{m:4,n1:1,n2:1,n3:1,a:1,b:1},drop:{m:1,n1:.5,n2:.5,n3:.5,a:1,b:1},ellipse:{m:4,n1:2,n2:2,n3:2,a:9,b:6},gear:{m:19,n1:100,n2:50,n3:50,a:1,b:1},heart:{m:1,n1:.8,n2:1,n3:-8,a:1,b:.18},heptagon:{m:7,n1:1e3,n2:400,n3:400,a:1,b:1},hexagon:{m:6,n1:1e3,n2:400,n3:400,a:1,b:1},malteseCross:{m:8,n1:.9,n2:.1,n3:100,a:1,b:1},pentagon:{m:5,n1:1e3,n2:600,n3:600,a:1,b:1},rectangle:{m:4,n1:100,n2:100,n3:100,a:2,b:1},roundedStar:{m:5,n1:2,n2:7,n3:7,a:1,b:1},square:{m:4,n1:100,n2:100,n3:100,a:1,b:1},star:{m:5,n1:30,n2:100,n3:100,a:1,b:1},triangle:{m:3,n1:100,n2:200,n3:200,a:1,b:1}};d3.superformulaTypes=d3.keys(r)})();

var size = 1000;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.superformulaTypes)
    .rangePoints([0, 960], 1);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 960)
    .attr("height", 500);

var big = d3.superformula()
    .type("square")
    .size(size * 50)
    .segments(360);

svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "big")
    .attr("transform", "translate(450,250)")
    .attr("d", big);

var circle = false;
setInterval(function() {
  circle = !circle;
  if(circle) {
     d3.select(".big").transition().duration(500).attr("d", big.type("circle"));
  } else {
     d3.select(".big").transition().duration(500).attr("d", big.type("square"));  
  }
}, 3000);
```

```css
path {
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.small {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.big {
  stroke: #666;
  fill: #ddd;
}

.small:hover {
  stroke: steelblue;
  fill: lightsteelblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```